# How to embed Android material icons such as "☰" or "⋮" in SMS / social-media messaging

Tags: sms, whatsapp-messenger, text-input, material-design

I often find myself in a difficult situation while trying to explain *how to* do something on an Android device or app to  people who are not Android literate.

For instance, if I write

> Press the hamburger menu or 3 dots menu

it doesn't make sense to them

whereas if I say

> Press the ☰ menu or ⋮ menu

they immediately understand

**How do I copy paste or embed material icons in text messages or in social media like WhatsApp ? App solutions are fine**

As a last resort, root solutions are acceptable.

You can find a list [material icons](https://material.io/tools/icons/) linked in [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/design/downloads).

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34755666) tangentially addresses but with no solution.

Even on this site, it would be far easier to explain using symbols, instead of cut-copy-upload-resize

Comment: Would it work to just phone the person? A lot of tech support is easier to do by phone than by SMS.

Comment: Thanks for your time. No. I am not into tech support. Besides, I can tell a group what to do and they act at their convenience

Comment: Would it work to copy and paste the text "Press the ☰ menu or ⋮ menu" from your question into a WhatsApp message? I don't use WhatsApp, but I know that many Android apps have good support for Unicode.

Comment: Yes, it does work on WhatsApp or SMS. That is the reason I chose them as examples :). I did search for apps having unicode support but somehow these codes aren't available - though they should be going buy comments on the SO question, I linked

Comment: Which material icons (other than "☰" or "⋮") do you want to embed, and in which app? Some of them have Unicode equivalents; others don't.

Comment: Most of the material icons linked in the question, if not all. SMS and WhatsApp is the target

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102572/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-unforgettableid).

Comment: Some workarounds might be to upload image files (showing the icon) or screenshots (annotated with bright red circles showing where to tap).  Or you could upload video with audio showing what to do.